# Why the strftime() PHP function can't convert and print this date? (obtained from a DB query)

Tags: php, date

I am pretty new in PHP and I have the following problem trying to print a formatted date obtained by a DB query.

I have this situation, into a page I have something like this:

```
<td><?php echo strftime('%F', $row['from_date']); ?></td>
```

The **$row['from_date']** is obtained performing a query on my DB and have this value: **1487721600** (I saw it using the PhpStorm debugger but also checking in the related field on the DB table).

Trying to evalueate (with the debugger tool) this statment **strftime('%F', 1487721600)** it says me **result=false**.

What is wrong?

Comment: this works for me, double check your `$row['from_date']` value

Comment: [Your code works fine.](https://eval.in/787354) `strftime()` will return false if the value passed to it is not a proper timestamp -- so you're probably not getting back from the database what you think you are.

Comment: @AlexHowansky From the DB I am obtaining this value: 1487721600. I think that it is a proper timestamp...

Comment: _"I am obtaining this value: 1487721600"_ I don't believe you are. Try: `var_dump($row['from_date'])`

Comment: Some formats are platform dependent you may have no this format http://stackoverflow.com/a/12362514/4471134

Comment: @AlexHowansky The var_dump give me this result: string '1487721600' (length=10)

Comment: Interesting, looks like @DanMiller might have the answer then...

Comment: Hmm docs don't say that `%F` is one of those values though...

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak.aspx Lists what is supported for Windows and `%F` is NOT listed.

Comment: What's wrong with `date('Y-m-d', $row['from_date'])` ???

Comment: @AbraCadaver this works. If you post as answer, I will accept it

Comment: @AbraCadaver Ah nice, I saw "and possibly others" on the `strftime()` page and my brain just stopped working there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all `strftime()` formats work on all platforms, for example [MSDN: strftime, wcsftime, _strftime_l, _wcsftime_l](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak.aspx) (for Windows) does not list the `%F` format.  I have never used it and prefer `date()` that is very flexible:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', $row['from_date']);
```